# Find the points of discontinuities of the function $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\sin (\pi x))^n-1}{(1+\sin (\pi x))^n+1},\forall x\in\Bbb R.$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

Find the points of discontinuities of the function $f$ defined by  $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\sin (\pi x))^n-1}{(1+\sin (\pi x))^n+1},\forall x\in\Bbb R.$

My sttempt so far:

We note that if $x\in\Bbb Z$ then $f(x)=0.$

Let $x\notin \Bbb Z.$

If $[x]=m\in\Bbb Z$ then, we have two cases.

If $m$ is even, we assume, $m=2k.$

Then, $2k\lt x\lt 2k+1\implies 2k\pi\lt \pi x\lt (2k+1)\pi$ and so, $$0\lt\sin\pi x\lt 1\implies 1\lt 1+\sin\pi x\lt 2.$$ This means $f(x)=1.$ So, $f(x)=1,$ if $[x]$ is even.

If $[x]=2k+1$ i.e odd then, $2k+1\lt x\lt 2k+2=2(k+1)\implies (2k+1)\pi\lt \pi x\lt 2(k+1)\pi$ and so, $$-1\lt \sin \pi x\lt 0\implies 0\lt 1+\sin\pi x\lt 1.$$ This means, $f(x)=-1.$ Hence, $f(x)=-1,$ if $[x]$ is odd.

So, $f(x)=0,$ if $x\in\Bbb Z,$ $f(x)=1$ if $[x]$ is even and $f(x)=-1$ if $[x]$ is odd.

Let $x\in\Bbb Z.$

If $x=2m,m\in\Bbb Z$ then $\lim_{x\to 2m+}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to 2m-}f(x)=-1.$ So, $f$ is discontinuous at $x.$

If $x=2m+1,m\in\Bbb Z$ then $\lim_{x\to (2m+1)+}f(x)=-1$ and $\lim_{x\to (2m+1)-}f(x)=1.$ So, $f$ is discontinuous at $x.$

So, $f$ is discontinuous at all integers.

---

Is my proof so far, which shows that $f$ is discontinuous at integers correct? Finally, how to conclude that for all non-integer points $f$ is continuous at those points? This is precisely where I am stuck. Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Nice try, but the issue is not that complicated.

Note that $0\leq 1+\sin(\pi x)\leq 2$ and
$a^{+\infty}=\begin{cases}0,0\leq a<1,\\
1,a=1,\\
\infty,a>1.
\end{cases}$, so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\sin(\pi x))^n-1}{(1+\sin(\pi x))^n+1}=
\begin{cases}-1,-1\leq \sin(\pi x)<0,\\
0,\sin(\pi x)=0,\\
1,0<\sin(\pi x)\leq 1.
\end{cases}.$$
So the points of discontinuity is $\mathbb{Z}$.